# Populate a csv which can be pulled into a data warehouse

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, powerbi, smartview

I am developing a report in Power BI using Oracle Smart View from HFM data.

Currently the report is generated using Excel and the Smart View plugin.

The thought is to run an Excel macro manually and populate a csv which can be pulled into a DWH and report off this.

Is it possible to pull the HFM data straight into Power BI? I am not sure how Smart View works. I would prefer to go straight to the HFM Db, but was told that is not possible.

Comment: How does the "excel macro" do it? I'm guessing Excel requires a plugin.

Comment: Does this help? http://poweronbi.com/2016/04/from-hyperion-planning-or-hyperion-financial-management-to-power-bi/ . Looks like your data source might just be an Oracle database.

Comment: Hi Nick, yes, smartview is an excel plug in from oracle. HFM is an oracle solution as far as I know.

Comment: You're best of getting direct access to the Oracle source and connecting to that in Power BI. But then you need to understand the tables and relationships

Comment: yes, i was hoping to do it that way. but corporate politics and policy are getting in the way. thanks for your help

Comment: You can now connect PowerBI and use native MDX. The May 2019 release should have what you need:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-may-2019-feature-summary/#essbase